# Google Maps API on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

My idea was to develop a traffic alert system on the android platform. Basically, I want to know what will be the modules of this project since Will this be advisable as my project? I say this because its my first time developing on android.

Right know, I know that I will be using Google maps API. But how will I show that if a particular area has a higher traffic? Will this be possible? Can we modify the map to show regions with higher traffic based on user data input in our application?

The map should show traffic jam with a red circle with a radius.

I was thinking that different users can from different parts of the city can use our application and report if a traffic jam has occurred in that area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll not be able to get traffic data from the Android Google Maps SDK.
Of course you could try to use the Web API but it is paid since a few months.

Regards

Comment: My application will allow users from different parts of the city to report traffic on a scale to 1-10. Based on this data, will I be able to show a red circle mark with a radius depending on what users are reporting? I don't need real time traffic data.

Comment: Of course - you're able to define a Map Overlay and do canvas painting stuff on that.